# How to use a polygon grid to calculate statistics on line and point features

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, zonal-statistics

What seems a simple task but I can't find the right tool to do it. I have a polygon grid cells and say a point feature class. I want to be able to create a table that contains the grid cell ID and for example the sum of points within that cell or the average of the value for those points. For a line feature I would like to simply have a 0/1 value if the line falls into a grid cell. I am doing this in ArcMap 10. This is like Zonal statistics but on a vector layer instead of a raster.

Answer (score 1):

Your "question" probably evaluates to about 3 questions but the answer to each is roughly the same.

I think there are two tools to look at for transferring your polygon identifier to lines and points:

- **[Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000)** which may also be able to do some/all of the statistics you are after using its merge rules
- **[Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/)** which will need a post processing step using **[Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000)** (for stats) or the **[Field Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Fundamentals_of_field_calculations/005s00000025000000/)** (for your 0/1)